# About a method for an integer to nth power using BigInteger to calculate big numbers

Tags: java

Question from the book:
Many encryption techniques depend on the ability to raise large integers to an integer power. Here is a method that implements a (reasonably) fast technique for integer exponentiation:

```
public static int pow(int x, int n) { 
    if (n == 0){
        return 1;
    }
    int t = pow(x, n/2);
    // find x to the n/2 recursively
    // if n is even, the result is t squared 
    // if n is odd, the result is t squared times x
    if (n%2 == 0){ 
        return t*t; 
    } else { 
        return t*t*x; 
    }
}
```

The problem with this method is that it only works if the result is smaller than 2 billion. Rewrite it so that the result is a BigInteger. The parameters should still be integers, though.

> You can use the `BigInteger` methods add and multiply, but don’t use `pow`, which would spoil the fun.

Well the method, I didn't really care how it works, but the "arrowed" part is the one that I'm confused about.  It says "don't use `pow`."  What does that mean? They give you the method and tells you to implement `BigInteger`, but what does it mean by "don't use pow?"  Does anyone know?

Comment: It means don't use the `pow` that's defined for `BigInteger`.  That is, don't use [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow-double-double-).  The example code shows a `pow` method that calls itself recursively.  You can write the same sort of thing using `BigInteger` methods.  Of course, if you call the method `pow` you can still use it recursively.  You just can't use `BigInteger.pow`.

Comment: So.. I'm not quite getting it. Does it mean change the whole pow method so that it uses BigInteger object by default instead of using BigInteger.pow?  I'm not sure what that second one does. Is that one of the methods in java library or is that pow referring to pow that the author created?

Comment: FYI that technique is called exponentiation by squaring, and it reduces the number of multiplications needed from n to lg N

Comment: What I meant was, change the whole `pow` method so that it uses `BigInteger` instead of `int`.  That's what I think they're looking for.  And yes, `BigInteger.pow` is one of the methods in the Java library, and you're not supposed to use it.  If you used it, the whole code would be just one line with no algorithm, but they're trying to get you to rewrite the algorithm using `BigInteger`.  And tell the instructor next time not to call their own method `pow`, which is confusing because it's the same name as a library method.

Comment: `pow` is a lousy name anyway.  It reminds me more of cartoon violence than exponentiation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a java.math.BigInteger Object there is a method pow.The

java.math.BigInteger pow(int)

Using this method you can calculate the the power of any number.

In your example we could use BigInteger to write the function as

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
public static BigInteger power(int a,int b){
BigInteger b1 = new BigInteger(Integer.toString());
b1 = b1.pow(b);
return b1;//returns a^b
}
```

Now using pow is built in function. I think that the statement means that you are expected to provide an alternate implementation of the process using different approach such as

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
public static BigInteger power(int a,int b){
BigInteger b1 = new BigInteger(Integer.toString(a));  
BigInteger b2 = new BigInteger("1");
for(int i = 0; i < b; i++){
b2=b2.multiply(b1);
}
return b2;//return a^b
}
```

Comment: Could you explain to me the Integer.toString() part please?  Why would you use it there?

Comment: Sorry for replying so late.....Integer.toString() is used to cast the integer to a String object. The constructor of BigInteger  has an argument of String

Comment: Note that you don't need to convert an integer to a string in order to make a `BigInteger` out of it.  You could say `BigInteger b1 = BigInteger.valueOf((long)a);`.  Since `BigInteger` stores the value as an array of binary integers, not of decimal digits, it should be more efficient to avoid the string conversion (which could matter if it's done in a loop several million times).

Comment: Thanks ! That would definitely be the better way to go about it.